# Is it possible to transfer ERC20 tokens without sending a transaction to the contract address?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

I'm trying to reverse engineer [etherscan](http://etherscan.io) so I can make my own explorer. While I was checking [Augur](https://etherscan.io/token/REP) token transfers I found a [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcfa0a4af6295057f64036d181574610984f97752b84e05bc15994c1fd1ec04cb) where both the to and from address where different from the token's smart contract address. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contracts can call other contracts while they are executed. You can see the calls made by this contract in the [Parity VM Trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xcfa0a4af6295057f64036d181574610984f97752b84e05bc15994c1fd1ec04cb&type=parity). In particular, here is the call to the token contract:

```
"action": {
  "callType": "call",
  "from": "0x25dde46ec77a801ac887e7d1764b0c8913328348",
  "gas": "0x9ca0",
  "input": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000009837cb670081ea411bfd26957f04a0da8663f9940000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  "to": "0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6",
  "value": "0x0"
},
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks. It is amazing etherscan has this much functionality. I wonder how it identified that transaction as a token transfer.

Comment: I absolutely agree! I'm pretty sure etherscan does this by listening to events. You can see [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcfa0a4af6295057f64036d181574610984f97752b84e05bc15994c1fd1ec04cb#eventlog) that your transaction triggered an event of the token contract. Therefore, all clients listening to events of the token contract were notified that a token transaction happened.

Comment: Yes indeed etherscan listens to Transfer() event.